# Run .net core 3.1 window service as Administrator need to start winform application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, service

I have developed a .net core 3.1 windows service (starttesterservice) that listens for request messages to start a winform tester applcation. The starttesterservice is run with elevated permissions via the app.mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">   
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

When the starttesterservice receives a test request message, it starts the winform tester.exe application.

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = exePath;
 startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine("c:\tester\", "tester.exe");
 startInfo.Verb = "runas";
 startInfo.Arguments = parameters;
 startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

 Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The tester application has a app.manifest to elevate it to admin permission as well.  Same app.manifest shown above.

When I run the starttesterservice in VS 2019, the windform tester UI gets launched without issue and the test can be completed.  However, when I run the starttesterservice as a windows 10 service the Tester UI is not displayed.  I'm using my domain user account as the service login account.  I have admin privilege's to the local machine.  The admin group has been added to the local security policy.  When I send the test request message to the starttesterservice the application is started without the UI being visible.  In the task manager I see the tester.exe process is running. I could use some advise on how to get the UI to be displayed so that the user can complete the test.

Comment: Services can’t start apps in a user session

Comment: Actually they can. `CreateProcessAsUser` can be used for that. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1071738/Launching-UI-Application-from-Windows-Service

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation... I will take a closer look tomorrow. There's a lot of information there.  Sounds like it will work.  I'll give it a shot and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Does anyone know whether the app.manifest UIAccess security attribute provides a possible solution to display the UI?  If so can you provide link or info...

Comment: I found this Microsoft uiAccess documentation:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations.  Seems like it's worth giving a try.  Has anyone done this and can give advise

Comment: Since Windows Vista services run under Session 0 and those are non-interactive, eg. they can't have an UI. The only way for a service to display an UI is to communicate with an application started on the users desktop session. That application can autostart when the user logs on or be started by the service using `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Comment: Also a service doesn't run under UAC and those ignores `requestedExecutionLevel` as it can not be elevated.

Comment: I downloaded the solution you suggested and I am in the process of testing it out,  I have a question for you regarding your previous post, what if service logon is the local service account do the requestexecutionleve/uiaccess app.mainfest attributes apply,  I was hoping that UIAccess would work based on the microsoft documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations  Let me what you think... Thanks

Comment: Services are not run under UAC and the UIAccess attribute applies only to UAC. As I said before a service is non-interactive and can not have an UI. Remember services run under Session 0, so a simple `Process.Start` will never work to display an UI on a user's desktop.

Comment: Worked great!  Need to work the concepts of the provide solution into my C# .Net Core 3.1 windows service now...  Thank you for everything.